# Project Euler problem #1 solution in C

Tags: c, programming-challenge

Any suggestions or comments? Is my style any good?

Initially I struggled with this problem as I found that using the "+=" operator gave the wrong results. I also tried a *while* loop the first time which was a baaaad idea. But what actually worked was using a static accumulator variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>





static unsigned long total;

int main(void)
{


  total = 0;





  for(unsigned int i = 1; i < 334; i++){

     total  = total + (3*i);


  }




  for(unsigned int j = 1; j < 1000; j++){

    if(j%5==0 && j%3!=0){

      total  = total + j;

    }else{

      total = total + 0;

    }


  }



  printf("Project Euler problem 1 solution = ");
  printf("%lu \n", total);


  return 0;
}
```

Ref: [Euler 1: Multiples of 3 and 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)

Comment: Is the copious amount of whitespace intended?

Comment: Please explain what that code is intended to do, briefly in the question title, and in more depth in the question body. As is your question lacks enough context to make it useful for future research.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is *very* hard to read since there is so much empty space. Even if we don't remove all of them, the following variant is *a lot* easier to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long total;

int main(void)
{
  total = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 1; i < 334; i++){
     total  = total + (3*i);
  }

  for(unsigned int j = 1; j < 1000; j++){

    if(j%5==0 && j%3!=0){
      total  = total + j;
    }else{
      total = total + 0;
    }
  }

  printf("Project Euler problem 1 solution = ");
  printf("%lu \n", total);

  return 0;
}
```

It fits even into the code example without any scrollbars.

---

There is no need to make `total` global. It should be a local variable.

---

Your first `for` loop uses an optimization, your second doesn't. That's asymmetrical. Use the same trick for both loops.

---

`total = total + 0` doesn't change `total` at all. The compiler will most likely throw that line away, but better don't include it.

---

The following `for` loop is easier to understand:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    total += i;
}
```

---

Concerning your comments on `+=`, did you accidentally use `total += total + j`? This will give wrong results. Otherwise I cannot reproduce your behaviour.

---

If you `printf` a `unsigned int`, you must use `%u`, not `%lu`, since the latter is meant for `unsigned long int`. Your compiler will warn you mismatching specifiers if you enable warnings.

---

If you apply those comments above, you end up with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int total = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3){
     total += i;
  }

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 5){    
    if(i % 3 != 0){
      total += i;
    }
  }

  printf("Project Euler problem 1 solution = %u \n", total);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mismatched specifier/type with `unsigned int total = 0; .... printf("Project Euler problem 1 solution = %lu \n", total);`.  This implies code was not compiled with a well enabled compiler.

Comment: @chux probably, but I have no idea what compiler OP uses. Added a section, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid unnecessary vertical spacing. On the other hand, a horizontal spacing around operators, braces, etc is necessary.
- Prefer `+=` where possible.
- `total = total + 0;` is a no-op. Remove it, along with an entire `else` clause.
- The `j` loop can be sped up 5-fold by incrementing `j` by five:

  ```
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j += 5) {
          if (j % 3 != 0) {
              total += j;
          }
      }
  ```

  Along the same line, the `i` loop can be rewritten as

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
          total += i;
      }
  ```

  Among other things, it avoids a magic number `334`, which needs some explanation (if you feel compelled to use your form, make it a constant with the meaningful name).
- That said, ProjectEuler problems are more about math than programming. Problem 1 doesn't need any coding whatsoever.